# Google Play refuses App (Logo not found)

Tags: android, google-play

I'd like to publish a new App on Google Play but it refuses it for an odd reason "Logo not found".

But I have a logo in my drawable folder and it even shows on the App so what is the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: you have change apk name?

Comment: Do you have the **512 x 512** High resolution app icon?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you uploaded all the REQUIRED images on the Store Listing section from Google Play Developer Console. The required fields will be red if they are required but you didn't fill them!